# XSLT Element to another with ID

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML code: (there are more channels and programmes in the original XML, I just shortened it)

```
<radio>
 <channel id="radio1">
  <display-name lang="en">Name of radio 1</display-name>
 </channel>
 <channel id="radio2">
  <display-name lang="en">Name of radio 2</display-name>
 </channel>

 <programme channel="radio1">
  <title lang="cs">Programme 1</title>
 </programme>
 <programme channel="radio1">
  <title lang="cs">Programme 2</title>
 </programme>
 <programme channel="radio2">
  <title lang="cs">Programme 3</title>
 </programme>
 <programme channel="radio2">
  <title lang="cs">Programme 4</title>
 </programme>
</radio>
```

And I need to make a XSLT that writes every channel name (Name of radio 1, Name of radio 2 etc) and also its programme titles. The HTML should look like this:

```
Name of radio 1
 Programme 1
 Programme 2
Name of Radio 2
 Programme 3
 Programme 4
```

But I just dont know how to get the programme title with the use of IDs (id in channel and channel in programme). IDK how to connect it in xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in a context where the current node is a `channel` element (e.g. in a template matching `channel` or in a `for-each` that selects `channel` elements) then you can find the corresponding `programme` elements with the XPath

```
/radio/programme[@channel = current()/@id]
```

(`current()` gives you the current `channel` element, we're filtering the `programme` elements to those whose `channel` attribute matches the current channel's `id`).

Alternatively you could define a [*key*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#key) that can extract `programme` elements given a `channel` value

```
<xsl:key name="programmesByChannel" match="programme" use="@channel" />
```

and then you can extract the matching programmes for the current channel using

```
key('programmesByChannel', @id)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method was just the thing I needed.